# How do I deal with counters to find the volume of 3D objects (Monte Carlo integration)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, counter, montecarlo

I am trying to find the volume of a sphere using monte carlo integration (for a project which has specifically asked for this method).

I have successfully managed to plot this in 3D for a sphere, but am struggling to get a numerical value.

I want to use counters and have used the following code successfully for 2D integration:

```
if np.absolute(y) <= np.absolute(f(x)):
        if f(x) > 0 and y > 0 and y <= f(x): counter += 1    
        if f(x) < 0 and y < 0 and y >= f(x): counter -= 1
```

When I plot it, I get the following error message:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have tried to include an np.any() fuction:

```
if np.any(np.absolute(y) <= np.absolute(f(x))):
        if np.any(f(x) > 0 and y > 0 and y <= f(x)): counter += 1    
        if np.any(f(x) < 0 and y < 0 and y >= f(x)): counter -= 1
```

But I still get the same error message.

I have also tried repeating the process for x, y, and z.

I would be really grateful for any advice on how to fix this. x

Comment: Could you update your question so that it contains a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: hi @lr1985, I'm very new to coding, what is an MCVE? Is that the rest of the Monte Carlo code?

Comment: Hi there. Don't worry, we are here to help. The page I have linked in my previous comment will tell you exactly what a MCVE is.